# How can I play HLS video from local storage

Tags: c#, android, video, unity-game-engine, http-live-streaming

I have HLS video sliced to several ts files and of course m3u file. I've built an Android app in Unity3d to play said video but after downloading it and not streaming it. All my efforts did not avail. Is it possible to "local stream" HLS video? Right now I'm using Easy Movie Texture and while it can play movies from local storage and from the Streaming Assets directory and of course stream HLS from a URL I cannot make it run as-is m3u that directs to the streaming assets.

Any suggestions how it can be done? Will gladly buy an asset from the store that can do it. I did not find one.

Please help and thanks in advance,
Shay.

P.S.
I'm not an Android developer, just Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at AvPro player for Android from RenderHead at Unity Asset Store: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/52745

It can stream video from URLs, I am not sure about HLS though. But before buying the asset, you can ask them on this forum:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-avpro-video-complete-video-playback-solution.385611/